# Compress string with GZipStream without using Base64

Tags: c#, gzip

I'm trying to compress a string as much as I can. I do have code that works when compressing to a Base64 string and decompressing from a Base64 string.

```
    public static string CompressString(string text)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            gZipStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        var compressedData = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
        memoryStream.Read(compressedData, 0, compressedData.Length);

        var gZipBuffer = new byte[compressedData.Length + 4];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(compressedData, 0, gZipBuffer, 4, compressedData.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gZipBuffer, 0, 4);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(gZipBuffer); // RETURNS AS BASE64
        //return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(gZipBuffer); // RETURN AS UTF8 STRING
    }

    public static string DecompressString(string compressedText)
    {
        byte[] gZipBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(compressedText); // BASE64 STRING TO BYTE ARRAY
        //byte[] gZipBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(compressedText); // UTF8 STRING TO BYTE ARRAY
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(gZipBuffer, 0);
            memoryStream.Write(gZipBuffer, 4, gZipBuffer.Length - 4);

            var buffer = new byte[dataLength];

            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                gZipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        }
    }
```

This works fine. However, if I switch `CompressString` to return `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(gZipBuffer)` instead of `Convert.ToBase64String(gZipBuffer)` and change `DecompressString` to read into the buffer using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(compressedText)` instead of `Convert.FromBase64String(compressedText)` I get an exception on the decompress (although the compress works fine).

`Additional information: The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.`

The problem with using Base64 is it results in a final compressed string that is 40% longer than using `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`

Is there any way I can compress the string without having the resulting string be base64 encoded?

Comment: Random bytes are not guaranteed valid Unicode, much less an encoding of such.. transmit as a byte[]; the core problem is trying to get “a string” out. At ‘best’ (for further transmission encoding) you may be able to use 7-bit clean ASCII encoding. Consider that base-64 is itself merely a 6-bit clean encoding mapped into the basic ASCII space.

Comment: @user2864740, transmit as a byte[]? I'm storing the resulting string in a database. The database column has a limited size. I need the string to be as small as possible. Removing that extra 30-40% added from the Base64 encoding would be very helpful.

Comment: So that’s the Y problem: the database column has the wrong type. Use binary/varbinary. Then “100%” of the bits will be used and there will be no encoding issues.

Comment: @user2864740 the database column is what it is. For most cases the size of the column is fine. The string I need to store happens to be very large.

Comment: It would probably be worthwhile to add another column and use it appropriately. (The unused column takes up effectively no space.)

Comment: The space of the column isn't the problem. The database isn't under my control. I don't even write to it directly. I write to it using a 3rd party library provided by the database owner. Changing the database simply isn't an option. It it was I wouldn't need the compression in the first place.

Comment: Then the very first step for such space “maximizing” is to identify the database text encoding. It probably “gets complicated” past a 7-bit clean binary stuffing. This only affords 7/8 vs 6/8 binary effectively, assuming a 1 byte encoding and no reserved control characters. If the encoding is 2-byte (eg. UCS-2 in the DB and UTF-16 during transmission) then one could hypothetically stuff into a Unicode string, after being careful to avoid codepoints that need surrogate pairs. This could get maybe 15/16 in said 2-byte encodings (better than 7/16 if DB uses a 2-byte encoding). YMMV with UTF-8.

Comment: Alternatively, consider using the “inefficient” Base64 with pre-shared dictionary; this can work very well for shorter strings.